# What is the easiest to change or replace an element with another

Tags: javascript, html, function

Whats the easiest way to completely replace a div and all its content with another div and all its content. I'm using an `a` element with onclick event to call a function, but i'm having trouble creating a function that works.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Freud Got Lynched</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@200;300;400;500;523;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="abertura" class="page0" style="display: block;">
    <video autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="assets/fundo1.webm" type="video/webm">
      </video>
      <div class="info">
          <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logobig">
          <p class="texto">Um documentário interativo inspirado nas obras do realizador David Lynch... 
            ou uma viagem pelo subconsciente incomum de pessoas comuns enquanto dormem.</p>
          <p class="sonhar">Sonhar</p>
          <a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('abertura','segunda')"><img src="assets/botao2.png" alt="botao" class="botao"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="segunda" class="page1" style="display: none;">
          <img src="assets/fundo.png" class="fundo">
                <div class="container">
                        <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav();">&times;</a>
                            <div class="overlay-content">
                              <ul><li><a href="#">Episódios</a></li>
                                <ul><li><a href="#">Episódio 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Episódio 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Episódio 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Episódio 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Episódio 5</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Episódio 6</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
                                <li><a href="sobre.html#autores">Autores</a></li>
                                <li><a href="sobre.html#creditos">Créditos</a></li>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="botaomenu" onclick="myFunction(this); openNav();">
                            <div class="bar1"></div>
                            <div class="bar2"></div>
                            <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
                <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logomedium" onclick="showPage('page0')"></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1,div2)
{
   var d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
   var d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
   if( d2.style.display == "none" )
   {
      d1.style.display = "none";
      d2.style.display = "block";
   }
   else
   {
      d1.style.display = "block";
      d2.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code you have tried?

Comment: @TamasSzoke added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not getting called, use the `onClick` method in the link:

```
href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="SwapDivsWithClick('abertura','segunda');"
```

With your code:

```js
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1, div2) {
  var d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
  var d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
  if (d2.style.display == "none") {
    d1.style.display = "none";
    d2.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    d1.style.display = "block";
    d2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abertura" class="page0" style="display: block;">
  <video autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="assets/fundo1.webm" type="video/webm">
      </video>
  <div class="info">
    <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logobig">
    <p class="texto">Um documentário interativo inspirado nas obras do realizador David Lynch... ou uma viagem pelo subconsciente incomum de pessoas comuns enquanto dormem.</p>
    <p class="sonhar">Sonhar</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="SwapDivsWithClick('abertura','segunda');"><img src="assets/botao2.png" alt="botao" class="botao"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="segunda" class="page1" style="display: none;">
  <img src="assets/fundo.png" class="fundo">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav();">&times;</a>
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Episódios</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Episódio 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Episódio 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Episódio 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Episódio 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Episódio 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Episódio 6</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
          <li><a href="sobre.html#autores">Autores</a></li>
          <li><a href="sobre.html#creditos">Créditos</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="botaomenu" onclick="myFunction(this); openNav();">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logomedium" onclick="showPage('page0')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works when i run the snippet, but when I try it with my html and javascript files nothing happens and I get this message: 

"Uncaught ReferenceError: SwapDivsWithClick is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index.html:21)"

Comment: Seems it does not find your `SwapDivsWithClick` function, make sure it is defined and added if it's in an external file.

Comment: I have the function, exactly as  written in your post, in the JavaScript file, and the my HTML with your suggested change on the "a" element. I have no idea what is missing. This has happened with several of my attempts so far.

Comment: Maybe it's worth a try to insert the `site.js` to the bottom, right before the closing body tag.

Comment: If you wrap the function inside `$(document).ready` or similar, that could cause the problem, put it outside.

Comment: I think i was able to get it going, but had to erase everything from the javascript file and start over. Will update you if something goes wrong again. Thanks.

Comment: supposed i wanted the original element to fade out and the new to fase in. Is there a way to adapt the existing function for that purpose?

Comment: Use jQuery's [fadeIn](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) methods or search about css fade animation.